# How can I parse this xml file?

Tags: dom, xml-parsing

First item

```
<item>
<title>...</title>
<link>...</link>
<guid>...</guid>
<description>...</description>
<pubDate>Thu, 31 Jan 2013 13:46:24 +0530</pubDate>
</item>
```

Second item

```
<item>
<title>...</title>
<link>...</link>
<guid>...</guid>
<description>...</description>
<enclosure url="http://entertainment.oneindia.in/img/2013/01/31-race-2-6-day-collection.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="202500"/>
<pubDate>Thu, 31 Jan 2013 10:36:35 +0530</pubDate>
</item>
```

"item" are the elements in a xml. First item don't have "enclosure" tag, while in second item, it is available. My DOMParser throws NPE, because the tag "enclosure" for which, it is searching is not available in first "item". How can I skip when preferred tag is not available?

My code with NPE is

```
objItem.setImage(getAttributeVal("enclosure", eElement));



public String getAttributeVal(String tag,Element eElement)
    {

        String imgUrl=eElement.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("url").getNodeValue();
        return imgUrl;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current code does not allow for missing instances.  It always assumes that it is present.

Modify your function to check if it exists.

```
public String getAttributeVal(String tag,Element eElement)
{
    if (eElement.GetElementsByTagName(tag).Length > 0) // Or .Count > 0
    {
       String imgUrl=eElement.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("url").getNodeValue();
       return imgUrl;
    }

    return ""; // Or null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use serialization, you can create class for enclosure

```
public class item
{
   public enclosure enclosure{get;set} // it is null if no corresponding xml presented.
}

public class enclosure 
{
   public string url {get; set;}
   public string type {get; set;}
   public string length {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JaxB api :

```
 import java.io.File;
 import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
 import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
 import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;



public static void main (String [] args) throws JAXBException {

File file = new File("myfile.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyItem.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller ();

MyItem item = (MyItem) unmarshaller.unmarshal (file);

String description = item.getDescription ();
String guid = item.getGuid ();
// ...
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "item")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public static class MyItem {

public MyItem () {
  // FOR JAXB SERIALISATION
}

public String getTitle () {
  return title;
}
public void setTitle (String title) {
  this.title = title;
}
public String getLink () {
  return link;
}
public void setLink (String link) {
  this.link = link;
}
public String getGuid () {
  return guid;
}
public void setGuid (String guid) {
  this.guid = guid;
}
public String getDescription () {
  return description;
}
public void setDescription (String description) {
  this.description = description;
}
public MyEnclosre getEnclosure () {
  return enclosure;
}
public void setEnclosure (MyEnclosre enclosure) {
  this.enclosure = enclosure;
}
public String getPubDate () {
  return pubDate;
}
 public void setPubDate (String pubDate) {
  this.pubDate = pubDate;
 }

@XmlElement(name = "title")
private String title;

@XmlElement(name = "link")
private String link;

@XmlElement(name = "guid")
private String guid;

@XmlElement(name = "description")
private String description;

@XmlElement(name = "enclosure")
private MyEnclosre enclosure;

@XmlElement(name = "pubDate")
private String pubDate;

}

public static class MyEnclosre {

public MyEnclosre () {
  //  FOR JAXB SERIALISATION
}

public String getUrl () {
  return myUrl;
}

public void setUrl (String url) {
  this.myUrl = url;
}

@XmlAttribute (name = "url")
private String myUrl;

}
```